# Class-level instance variables not available in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project with the following:

controller: patient/edit

```
 def edit
   if current_user.nil?
   redirect_to new_user_session_path
 else
   @states = State.all
   @display_dashboard = true
   @patient
   @foo = 1
 end
end
```

view patient/edit

```
<%= @patient.inspect %>
<%= @states.inspect %>
<%= @foo.nil? %>
```

I run byebug on the `edit` action and @patient has a value, so does @states.  However, I can't see @patient on the view.  Any ideas? I'm baffled.

Comment: Your edit action is returning @patient? are you setting @patient in a `before_action?`

Comment: `before_action :set_patient, only: [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy,:dashboard,:allergies,:occupations, :information, :revisions]`

Comment: my before_action allows for :edit, which references @patient

Comment: remove @patient from your edit action, and see if that changes anything   if it is set in the before_action, then it already exists, and unless you are doing something with it (IE modifying it) no need to reference it in the edit action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@patient` doesn't have a value, clearly. If it has a value in the controller action and you've verified this, then you're "emptying" it somewhere in the views.

Change the `@patient.inspect` to `@patient.nil?` or `@patient.blank?` and see if `true` is displayed.

If you're absolutely certain that the controller value isn't showing up, then do this:

```
@states = 1
```

And see if 1 shows up on the view for `@states`

Perhaps it's some other action altogether.

Comment: @patient already has a value within the class.  I only put it there to assure there was a value passing through the action. It does indeed have a value

Comment: i've updated the question.  i've included `@foo`.  On the view, `@foo` shows up as nil, yet `@states` has a value. Could there be something else in the controller I'm missing?

Comment: you're right, it still shows as the same value, not 1.  We use knockoutjs but I didn't think that could affect a new instance variable i put in the action.  I'm still unable to find where it's coming from

Comment: It ended up being a variable that was drawn from another action (not edit) and that action was not included in the `:before_action`